# serve react-flask app with nginx tutorial doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, flask

I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react--flask-project) in order to learn how to serve **react** and **flask** apps with one single **nginx** server.

I already reached the point in the tutorial where **nginx** should be serving the **React** app, but I still can only see default **nginx** page.

This is my nginx app configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/agroware`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/ubuntu/agroware/frontend/build;
    index index.html;
    

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 
    location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

I believe I am following the tutorial, but I cannot see the **react** app to this point.

Comment: Have you removed sites-available/default and restarted nginx?

Comment: Any updates? I also have this issue